# Crazyhouse Chess: is it possible to get all eighteen queens?

Tags: chess, variants

Over [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/5868/20384) it was previously discussed whether one can end up with all nine queens.

There is a variant of chess called [Crazyhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazyhouse) in which captured pieces may be reintroduced as the capturer's. In theory, then, a player may have two queens and sixteen pawns which all may be promoted.

Is it possible to get eighteen queens without checkmating before that, or else putting the opponent into a draw?

Answer (score 2):

If that is the goal of both players, should be easy to achieve.  Simply move weak side king away from his 1st rank and build a wall of minor pieces between him and the passed pawns.  With a little more effort a player with a huge lead could force the king out and achieve the same thing.